# HTC text photos

Tags: photos, gallery, htc

I have an HTC from Sprint and today the text photos changed. There was an option to choose Photo or Gallery and I chose Photo "all the time" and now when I click on a message photo is does not open. It just says Media not Found. How can I undo this??

Comment: First: What are "text photos"? Where did you chose "photo or gallery"? And what HTC device is it? Could you pleae [edit] your question and add those details? Otherwise it's hard for us to help you, as we cannot see what your issue is about.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options:

- The very extreme: Uninstalling *Google+* as described by [Miguel's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/57026/16575). This will work because the new "Photos" app is part of Google+; an uninstalled app can no longer be the default one.
- Installing another gallery app (there are plenty of nice alternatives available, like e.g. [QuickPic](http://www.appbrain.com/app/quickpic/com.alensw.PicFolder)). As this introduces an additional option, the system will ask you again which app to use.
- Go to *Settings→Apps*, switch to the "All" tab. Scroll to the *Photos* app (if not found, try the *Google+* App), open its entry, and "clear defaults". No additional install/uninstall required, this will simply "undo" your action as requested.
- Take a look at [Default App Manager](http://www.appbrain.com/app/default-app-manager-lite/com.appiator.defaultappmanager), which allows you the same in a more convenient way (e.g. much easier when you don't know which app holds the default).

Answer (score -1):

I uninstalled google+ from my phone, and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Was having same problem opening pictures attached to text message: `Media Not Found` and/or `Google+ has stopped working`. Removing the updates solved the problem.